# Dynamic Linq FirstOrDefault Statement

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Using C# 7+, I am instantiating a variable via a FirstOrDefault() statement. But it's repeated throughout the code for different variables. I'm wondering if/how I can build these statements dynamically.  This is what I currently have (notice that the variable name matches the DataTable name)

```
var generalSolution = this.GeneralSolution.FirstOrDefault();
var pieceModel = this.PieceModel.FirstOrDefault();
.... many more of these same variable declarations.....
```

What I would like to do is given a list of strings, create each of these variables iteratively.  Something like:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    var somename = this."item".FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is this even, at all, possible?

Comment: You can get a field using reflection `System.Reflection.FieldInfo`, but how could you create variables in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Local, designed to be passed as parameter values to some stored procedure.  I'm from a DBA background, and starting to work with code that is literally 100's of lines of these types of variable assignments - specifically var nameofthing = this.nameofthing.FirstOrDefault(). Because of this concrete pattern, it seems like there has to be a better way to do this programatically (I may be wrong tho!)

Comment: "Better" is subjective. MickelsonMichael mentions reflection and yes, you can do that, but as I like to say, "reflection is mad science." You're no longer programming to the goal; you're programming to programming to the goal [sic]. In other words, it's meta-programming. The intent of your code can get lost and that reduces maintainability. Frankly, trying to simplify this pattern probably isn't the best use of your energy.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps with more information you would get more helpful answers. For example, what are the types of `GeneralSolution` or `PieceModel`? Think about how you would expect to write code to use the variables when you don't know their names or even that they exist?

Comment: You seem to have inherited code from a maniac or possibly even a contractor, but if the code works reliably, you may be well-advised to leave it as it is. The alternative would be fully refactoring it, rather than just cleaning up the odd idiom while leaving the essential horror in full bloom. If you'll be expected to add substantial chunks of functionality going forward, I would almost certainly write very different code than the old guy did. Maybe the refactoring would be a suitable question for [s/w engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). Here, it would be off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with reflection, but it will require some work to get it into an easy to work with format and may not be recommended.

[See this dotnetfiddle for a quick example I threw together](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7A5ctU)

Essentially you can get all the properties of `this` by using the `typeof(this).GetProperties()` method. That will return you a list of `PropertyInfo` objects that you can then iterate through as I did in the fiddle. However, if there are any other properties on `this` you will also grab those, so you can use [BindingFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8) within the overload of the [GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) function.

In the end it will probably be best for you to create some sort of container that has properties that you expect and want to iterate through. Or better yet, you may just have to accept that you are going to do a lot of `FirstOrDefaults`, which is a much safer route to go. Reflection can be tricky and confusing

Feel free to ask any questions and I'll be happy to go into more detail